# NodeJs, AngularJS 502 error — Deployment: Cloudfront + S3 (Angular) + Ec2 (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-502

I am facing cors issue on my website deployed on amazon aws.

1. The frontend is deployed using S3 + Cloudfront (URL: https://example.com)
2. Backend is deployed on EC2, with Load Balancer. (URL: https://api.example.com)

**Now when my frontend angular app hit request on the api, it doesn't work in the first go, and throw the cors error like this:**

[image]

**Now when i refresh the same page, It works fine. This is after refresh api calls:**

[image]